# how to secure json RPC between console apps in c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, https, rpc

I have a pair of console apps. The server uses nowin as webserver. The client issues json RPCs to this server.

My question is, how do I secure communication between these two apps?

I'm currently using https with a selfsigned certificate (embedded into the assembly) on the server. Client checks server's certificate thumbprint. Server checks client's basic auth.

Embedding certificate into server's assembly seems insecure. How do I prevent one from dissambling it reading it?

Should I use client certificate instead?

Comment: Is it an MVC app that JSon speaks with?

Comment: It is not a MVC APP.